# Do about 10 people die from unintentional drowning daily?

Tags: mortality

Is it true that 10 people die from unintentional drowning daily as this [article](http://www.popsci.com/secondary-and-dry-drowning#page-2) claims?

> Either way, secondary and dry drowning are both incredibly rare. In
>   fact, as The Washington Post reports, while the Centers for Disease
>   Control and Prevention say that about **10 people die** from unintentional
>   drowning **daily**, the agency doesn't even collect statistics on “dry
>   drowning.”

Comment: There are people dying from intentional drowning? Ah, maybe suicides. Is that statistically significant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reference to the CDC&P suggests that this statistic is limited to deaths in the United States.

You can see, for instance, the CDC&P document ["Deaths: Final Data for 2014" (PDF)](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nvsr/nvsr65/nvsr65_04.pdf) (*National Vital Statistics Reports* vol 65 num 4), date June 30, 2016 (so presumably the 2015 data has not yet ben published).  Table 10 lists "Number of deaths from 113 selected causes".  On page 44, you can see "Accidental drowning and submersion" with 3,406 deaths reported.  That is an average of 9.33 deaths per day, so pretty close to the report you cited.